# Is it possible to install SSD with 6Gb/s in Mac pro Mid 2010?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, mac

Is it possible to install Solid State Drive with 6Gb/s speed in Mac pro Mid 2010?

Comment: You need to provide detailed model number for question like this.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence - I have a Samsung EVO 840 1TB working just fine in my Mac Pro 3,1 Early 08 - though at restricted 3Gb speeds.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it should be possible to install a SSD with SATA 6Gb/s.

The [MacPro5,1](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=MacPro5,1) was offered with a 512 GB SSD by Apple actually. The internal interface is limited to 3 Gb/s (which roughly translates to 300 MByte/s max) though. As a consequence you will not benefit from the faster transfer rate of the SATA III SSD.

The same is valid for [MacBookPro6,1](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=MacBookPro6,1) and [MacBookPro6,2](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=MacBookPro6,2).

SATA 6Gb/s is [backward compatible](https://www.sata-io.org/sata-naming-guidelines) with SATA 3Gb/s. Some features recently implemented in SATA 6Gb/s won't work if a respective device is attached to a SATA 3Gb/s interface (e.g. `Isochronous Native Command Queuing`).